# Reading the header of a file in java

Tags: java, file-type

Does any one know how to read the header of a file in java using "magic numbers" or ascii values to get the name of the extension of a file

Comment: do you mean the file name by "header of a file"?

Comment: He means the first few bytes, specifically in an image or media file. Technically you probably could consider it a "header" I suppose. Judging by his previous question he doesn't seem to understand that the "extension" is part of the filename.

Comment: @BrianRoach I am a girl...and u r right I should identify the file type by readin the first few bytes like a header. I dont understand it much so al the help is appreciated

Comment: @talnicolas I should identify the first few bytes of a file by reading its header in order to know the file extension

Comment: @sue yin, the general solution to the problem you are describing is not at all simple.  Do you have some specific file types you want to distinguish between?

Comment: @sue yin:  While the start of a file can be used fairly reliably for determining a [file type](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_type), on every system with which I am familiar, the file extension cannot be definitively determined from [magic numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)#Magic_numbers_in_files) at the start of a file.  For example nothing prevents you from putting a .txt extension on an executable file.

Comment: @PTBNL Yeah ...even if u change the name of the extension it should still be able to tell u the correct extension o fthe file by reading the header of that file...

Comment: @msandiford kinda..like pdf, mp3, docx, mp4, mov, jpeg, png, gif

Comment: @talnicolas: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_format#File_header

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe not the answer you wanted, but as you gave us very little information ...

In unixoid systems (Linux, Mac, *BSD) you have the [file](http://linux.die.net/man/1/file) command, that

> tests each argument in an attempt to classify it. There are three sets of tests, performed in this order: filesystem tests, magic tests, and language tests. The first test that succeeds causes the file type to be printed.

E.g.

```
$ file linux-image-3.1.0-030100rc10-generic_3.1.0-030100rc10.201110200610_amd64.deb
linux-image-3.1.0-030100rc10-generic_3.1.0-030100rc10.201110200610_amd64.deb: Debian binary package (format 2.0)
```

Using [Runtime.exec(...)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec%28java.lang.String%5b%5d,%20java.lang.String%5b%5d,%20java.io.File%29) you could invoke that program and parse its output.

#### Edit 1:

To determine if a given file is a [PNG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Network_Graphics):

```
import java.io.*;

public class IsPng {

    public static void main(String ...filenames) throws Exception {
        if(filenames.length == 0) {
            System.err.println("Please supply filenames.");
            return;
        }

        for(String filename : filenames) {
            if(isPng(new File(filename))) {
                System.out.println(filename + " is a png.");
            } else {
                System.out.println(filename + " is _not_ a png.");
            }
        }
    }

    private static final int MAGIC[] = new int[] { 0x89, 0x50, 0x4e, 0x47, 0x0d, 0x0a, 0x1a, 0x0a };

    private static boolean isPng(File filename) throws Exception {
        FileInputStream ins = new FileInputStream(filename);
        try {
            for(int i = 0; i < MAGIC.length; ++i) {
                if(ins.read() != MAGIC[i]) {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            return true;
        } finally {
            ins.close();
        }
    }

}
```

#### Edit 2:

Sometimes [URLConnection.getContentType()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html#getContentType%28%29) works, too, for local files:

```
new File(name).toURI().toURL().openConnection().getContentType()
```

But your comments sound like you *have to* implement the method by yourself, not using external programs (?).

Comment: I do not understand wat u jus typed..I dont think that code is what am lookin for.. I think it is a bit simpler tahn that...at least i hope...thanks still

Comment: I added an example which determines if a given file is a [.png](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Network_Graphics). You would need to test many magics, though, if you want to support multiple filetypes.

Answer (score 2):

You can try [JFileChooser](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JFileChooser.html). Here is an example.

```
import java.io.*;
import javax.swing.*;

class GetFileType {
  public static void main(String[] args){
    JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
    File file = new File("Hello.txt");

    String fileTypeName = chooser.getTypeDescription(file);
    System.out.println("File Type= "+fileTypeName);
  }
}
```

This will output Text Document. If it is a MP3 file passed then the output will be MP3 Format Sound.