# Read file headers using java

Tags: java, binary-data, java-io, preon

I am trying to read file headers using java,
I want to get file type(image, audio whatever).
I have tried many examples but nothing seems to work.
I tried preon and no luck,
can some one tell me how to read file headers using preon or some other Java apis
thanks...

Comment: See this duplicate to aid achieve that.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8191720/reading-the-header-of-a-file-in-java

Comment: Check also this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/51438/getting-a-files-mime-type-in-java

Comment: Define "nothing seems to work" and "no luck". Specifically, what results are you expecting and what results are you actually getting? and with what code? against what files?

Comment: @Eric I know this comment is late, but please accept an answer instead of editing "closed" into the title.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [mime-util's](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mime-util/) MagicMimeMimeDetector:

```
detector.getMimeTypes(file)
```

Answer (score 4):

```
 File f = new File(filepath);
 System.out.println("Mime Type of " + f.getName() + " is " +  
 new MimetypesFileTypeMap().getContentType(f));
```

Comment: it only works if file has an extension, I am trying to read unknown file types (like temp, dump files without any .extension)