# how can I get the extension from a file in java?

Tags: java

I have a problem. I have some file without extension and I need discover the extension. How can I do that? I think the only way is to read the file, but i don't know  how I can understand the extension.
Thanks

Comment: Show some code. What you did?

Comment: @Arpit: They didn't mean to get the file extension, rather recognize the file format without having the extension

Comment: You could use [Apache Commons IO](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16202288/284538) for this.

Comment: @Wonderb0lt: Correct!, removed it. Thanks.

Comment: Perhaps you could edit the question to clarify that you want **to check the file type** of a file, not just substring the extension out of the file name.

Answer (score 1):

To probe the content of a `File` you could use the [nio](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/package-summary.html) Java API and the method [`probeContentType`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#probeContentType(java.nio.file.Path))

Answer (score 0):

If your file has no extension (as you said) you cannot read the extension, because it is not present.

You could read the start of the file and look for some indicators of the content. E.g. most `.pdf` files start with `%PDF-1.5` (or a different version number) in the content.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the only way is read the magic number of the file...how?

Check this thread [Reading the header of a file in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8191720/reading-the-header-of-a-file-in-java)

Hope that help you!

Answer (score 0):

Without extension, it's tough to find the format (but it's possible).

Even `Windows` asks you What to do when you click on `Open With..` on a file without extension.